# Exception in Application start method JavaFX 1.8

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, cmd, javafx-8

I'm having trouble running JavaFX Program which runs on Java version 1.8. I noticed that even if I can run this program on Intellij IDE, it throws

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

error when I try running it in command line. There are no errors when I use "javac Main.java" but it throws the error after I compile it then type "java Main.java"

Here are the files

src folder

- controller folder

  - Controller.java
- model folder

  - Database.java
- view folder

  - loginview.fxml
  - registerview.fxml
  - mainmenu.fxml
- Main.java

Main.java

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import model.Database;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("view/mainmenu.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Test Program");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 600));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Database db = new Database();
        db.testmethod();

        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Controller.java

```
package controller;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Controller {

    public void exitProgram() {
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public void openRegister(ActionEvent event) {
        Parent root;
        try {
            root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("view/registerview.fxml"));
            javafx.stage.Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setTitle("Register User");
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 600));
            stage.setResizable(false);
            stage.show();

            close(event);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void openLogin(ActionEvent event) {
        Parent root;
        try {
            root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("view/loginview.fxml"));
            javafx.stage.Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setTitle("Login User");
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 600));
            stage.setResizable(false);
            stage.show();

            close(event);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void close(ActionEvent event) {
        ((Node) (event.getSource())).getScene().getWindow().hide();
    }
}
```

Database.java

```
package model;

public class Database {

    public void testmethod(){
        System.out.println("TEST METHOD");
    }

}
```

loginview.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>


<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="controller.Controller">
   <children>
      <Label layoutX="134.0" layoutY="145.0" prefHeight="165.0" prefWidth="332.0" text="LOGIN" />
   </children>
</Pane>
```

mainmenu.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>

<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="controller.Controller">
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="buttonReg" layoutX="32.0" layoutY="60.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#openRegister" prefHeight="104.0" prefWidth="521.0" text="OPEN REGISTER" />
      <Button fx:id="buttonLogin" layoutX="32.0" layoutY="211.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#openLogin" prefHeight="104.0" prefWidth="521.0" text="OPEN LOGIN" />
      <Button fx:id="buttonExit" layoutX="32.0" layoutY="356.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#exitProgram" prefHeight="104.0" prefWidth="521.0" text="EXIT" />
   </children>
</Pane>
```

registerview.fxml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

   <?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
   <?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>


   <Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="controller.Controller">
      <children>
         <Label layoutX="130.0" layoutY="145.0" text="REGISTER" />
      </children>
   </Pane>
```

The error in command line

```
TEST METHOD
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$1(LauncherImpl.java:182)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException:
/C:/Users/Bryan/Desktop/TESTRUN/src/view/mainmenu.fxml:6

        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:103)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:922)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:971)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:220)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:744)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
        at Main.start(Main.java:13)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$8(LauncherImpl.java:863)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$7(PlatformImpl.java:326)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$5(PlatformImpl.java:295)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$6(PlatformImpl.java:294)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$3(WinApplication.java:177)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: controller.Controller
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:920)
        ... 22 more
Exception running application Main
```

I noticed that Database runs before throwing the Error. I don't understand what's the cause of this error

Comment: worksforme (fx8 and current fx15) ..

Answer (score 0):

on Main.java,

add

```
import controller.Controller
```

Comment: hmm .. that sounds weird (why would the main need to import a class it never uses?). As  I could not reproduce the problem with the example you provided, I would guess the problem was elsewhere and the import accidentally solves it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having buttons like "Buttons" try to put them with the class
"JFXButton"

You have this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>

<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="controller.Controller">
    <Button fx:id="buttonReg" layoutX="32.0" layoutY="60.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#openRegister" prefHeight="104.0" prefWidth="521.0" text="OPEN REGISTER" />
    <Button fx:id="buttonLogin" layoutX="32.0" layoutY="211.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#openLogin" prefHeight="104.0" prefWidth="521.0" text="OPEN LOGIN" />
    <Button fx:id="buttonExit" layoutX="32.0" layoutY="356.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#exitProgram" prefHeight="104.0" prefWidth="521.0" text="EXIT" />
</Pane>
```

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>

<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="controller.Controller">
    <JFXButton fx:id="buttonReg" layoutX="32.0" layoutY="60.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#openRegister" prefHeight="104.0" prefWidth="521.0" text="OPEN REGISTER" />
    <JFXButton fx:id="buttonLogin" layoutX="32.0" layoutY="211.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#openLogin" prefHeight="104.0" prefWidth="521.0" text="OPEN LOGIN" />
    <JFXButton fx:id="buttonExit" layoutX="32.0" layoutY="356.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#exitProgram" prefHeight="104.0" prefWidth="521.0" text="EXIT" />
</Pane>
```

Comment: why would using a different type of button (particularly one that's not even imported in the fxml) help?

Comment: While I was first time working with fxml I had this same error and when I changed it to JFXButton it worked. I don´t know why, but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The `InvocationTargetException` is occurring because the call to method `getResource()` – in method `openRegister()` of class `Controller` – is returning null. You can check this by simply printing out the value returned by method `getResource()`, for example

```java
System.out.println(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("view/registerview.fxml"));
```

It is returning null because method `getResource()` builds an absolute path to the file `registerview.fxml` and then checks to see whether such a file exists. The absolute path that method `getResources()` builds is **not** the actual path to the file. Hence you need to change the method argument, i.e. "view/registerview.fxml"

I'm guessing that the below solution is not the only solution, but it worked for me.

In order to prevent getting the `InvocationTargetException` I did the following.

1. I put class `Main` in a package which I named `jfxtests`.
   (It is not clear to me, from your question, whether `Main` is in a package or not.)
2. I made the `controller` folder and the `view` folder sub-packages of `jfxtests`.
3. I call method `getClass().getResource()` and not `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource()`.
4. In class `Controller`, I changed the argument that I pass to method `getResource()`.

The only change I made was to class `Controller`. Here it is with my changes:

```java
package jfxtests.controller;  // changed package

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Controller {

    public void exitProgram() {
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public void openRegister(ActionEvent event) {
        Parent root = null;
        try {
            root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/jfxtests/view/registerview.fxml"));  // changed this line
            javafx.stage.Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setTitle("Register User");
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 600));
            stage.setResizable(false);
            stage.show();

            close(event);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void openLogin(ActionEvent event) {
        Parent root;
        try {
            root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/jfxtests/view/loginview.fxml"));  // changed this line
            javafx.stage.Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setTitle("Login User");
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 600));
            stage.setResizable(false);
            stage.show();

            close(event);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void close(ActionEvent event) {
        ((Node) (event.getSource())).getScene().getWindow().hide();
    }
}
```

Note that since I changed the package for class `Controller`, I also had to change the FXML files.

```
fx:controller="jfxtests.controller.Controller"
```